# What other ways are there to access the shell on Linux other than the plaintext-login shell prompt, teminal emulators on GUI and virtual consoles?

Tags: linux, shell

Read it somewhere that there are **several other ways**, but that these three are the most common ones. So was doing some research on the topic and haven't found any other way, yet. Are there any other ways of accessing a shell session on Linux, other than the ones mentioned in the question title?

Comment: Many programming languages provide facilities for spawning a shell. For example https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Both C and awk have a `system()` function call that initiates a child shell (which can run any script or command). Both also have syntax to initiate any command (including a shell) such that the caller may either write to stdin, or read from stdout, of the child command. The scheduler commands `cron` and `at` can initiate shells at predetermined times. Most editors have syntax that lets you invoke a shell (using a selected area of the current file as input and output).

Comment: Ah, should have thought of cron and at myself. Thanks!

Comment: e.g. ssh/telnet, or serial (not sure whether this falls into "plaintext-login shell prompt" for you though)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35271850

Comment: @mifritscher: it does but remote access is still a valid answer I guess. Thanks.